# loading image during delay

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, loading, delay

I got the delay to work when you click on the buttons but I cant get the loading gif to display during the delay.

Thanks

```
function () {
    $('.sectionThreeTab:not(.tabActive)').click(function () {
        $('ajax-loader.gif').bind('ajaxStart', function () {
            $(this).show();
        }).bind('ajaxStop', function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
        $('.tabActive').removeClass('.tabActive');
        $(this).addClass('tabActive');
        var lesson = $(this).attr('lesson');
        var self = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'lessons/' + lesson + '.htm',
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#sectionTabContent').append(data);
                }
            })
        }, 3000);
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: please post your HTML for the ajax-loader.gif image - I believe your targeting this image incorrectly.

Comment: '<div id="loading" class="grayBackground withBorder10" style="display:none"> <img alt="Loading..." src="img/ajax-loader.gif">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this instead of what you have:
Delete this part:

```
$('ajax-loader.gif').bind('ajaxStart', function () {
            $(this).show();
        }).bind('ajaxStop', function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
```

And change the setTimeout to this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
            $("#loading").show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'lessons/' + lesson + '.htm',
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#sectionTabContent').append(data);
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $("#loading").hide();
                }
            })
        }, 3000);
```

Please also post your html so we can see if everything else is in order.

Edit:

```
<div id="loading" class="grayBackground withBorder10" style="display:none"> 
<img alt="Loading..." src="img/ajax-loader.gif" />
</div>
```

Comment: '<div id="loading" class="grayBackground withBorder10" style="display:none"> <img alt="Loading..." src="img/ajax-loader.gif">

Comment: Well, have you tried what I posted? Is it working? (If it doesn't show, you can also check if the path to your gif file is correct).

Comment: It isnt working! I have gone through the code multiple times and I cant figure it out!!

Comment: Ok I got it now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I believe your targeting the loading image incorrectly, try:

```
$('#ajaxLoader').bind('ajaxStart', function () {
    $(this).show();
}).bind('ajaxStop', function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Where your loading image has an Id `#ajaxLoader` (replace to suit your HTML).

Comment: One other error I see in there, $('.tabActive').removeClass('.tabActive');
should be $('.tabActive').removeClass('tabActive');

Comment: Alright I changed it to the below code but it still doesnt show the gif!                                                   $("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
     $(this).show();
 }).bind('ajaxStop', function () {
     $(this).hide();
 });

Comment: '<div id="loading" class="grayBackground withBorder10" style="display:none">
    <img alt="Loading..." src="img/ajax-loader.gif">'